# Linux is it possible to run script as file owner?

Tags: linux

I am sorry that I don't know this is the correct place or not. I am in a hurry, racing with the time. I have a file which has following attributes in a Linux machine. (kernel 2.6.26)

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 2015-06-01 08:08 /usr/bin/runme
```

I don't have root privileges in machine and I don't know root password. Is it possible to run this script as it's owner. I have write and compile some c code in a different file but it didn't work. The code I've used;

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {        
     setuid(0);
     system("/bin/bash /usr/bin/runme"); 
}
```

Then someone said that use execve, but result is not changed. Here is the code when I use execve;

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {        
        extern char * const environ[];
    char * const command[] = {"runme", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL};
    execve("/usr/bin/runme", command, environ);
}
```

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The irony that I've opened this issue to stack overflow and they've said same thing what you said. So what should I do with my question?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but one you have to be extremely careful with - your script has global read-write privileges, which means *anyone* could change it, and therefore could do *anything* as root.

That's a hair raising sort of a security hole. If you want to get a *normal* binary to run as a user you need to add the `setuid` flag to the binary with `chmod g+s`. This you will have to do as root, because that's also opening a massive security hole if you didn't.

If you want to do with a script... it depends on the scripting language. Some (indeed - many) will just refuse to work, because of the way they're implemented - again, security risk.

I would suggest that the root (sic) to go here is to look at `sudo` - it's a "super user do", and allows non privileged users to run commands as privileged (or root) accounts. Then - once configured - you can:

```
sudo /path/to/script
```

Although, I still really wouldn't leave that script world writable. That's still a security risk.

If you don't have root, no root password and no admin access... then I would suggest that that's because it's NOT your system, and you stop trying to do this, because it's probably Computer Misuse and may be a crime depending where you live.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. There is no risk for being a crime, just need to run that script file with root privileges. I've edit that file and put some code to connect me. I am able to run it but it runs with my privileges.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (without using a vulnerability) to run a script (or any executable) as another user unless that user has granted you that right at some point.

For "real" executables, this can be done using the setuid bit, which can be set by the file owner. For scripts, modern environments typically ignore the setuid bit, so you would need some kind of wrapper (either a custom one, or sudo). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts for further details.

Your specific case is an excellent example of how the setuid bit can be dangerous.
Having the setuid bit on a file that is world writable and executable would allow you to execute any command as the file owner. As the file owner is actually root, replacing the content of such a file with, for example, the content of bash would grant you a root shell.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, one more question, what is should be written in that file to have a root shell? I've tried everything with execve and execl as you see. But I couldn't get a root shell. Is there an example for this?

Comment: I said it *would* be. In your case the file doesn't have the setuid bit set, and only the file owner (or root) can set it.